# Setup normal screeshot procedure?

Tags: kde, screenshot, plasma-5, print-screen

If I press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button, a *Spectacle* application starts and allows me to take screenshot with following key and mouse strokes.

Can I make it proceed immediately, without additional actions?

If *Spectacle* application is already started, then nothing happens on <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button.

I.e. depending on status of *Spectacle* application, I should either press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> or look for *Spectacle* application in the list of running application -- a lot of additional actions.

Can I make application activated on <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button?

Comment: Can you clarify "Can I make application activated on PrintScreen button?"

Comment: Please see if the edit is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, there are other "default" actions provided in *Settings > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts* as shown in the image below:

[image: Spectacle options]

1. <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> opens the Spectacle GUI. If the application is already open but in the background or minimized, pressing <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> doesn't bring the GUI back into focus or above other windows. As you noted, you'll need bring it to the front yourself.
2. If you want to take a full screen screenshot, instead of <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to immediately do so without invoking the Spectacle GUI.
3. Similarly, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> lets you immediately screenshot the active window.
4. The fourth default option available is <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> if you want to select a particular area of the screen.

As you can see, if you want to carry out any of the options in **2**, **3**, or **4**, you don't need to press just <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and then have to deal with Spectacle's GUI. The three options execute immediately without invoking Spectacle's GUI.

However, if you want to do something not covered by the three actions described above, you will need to use <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and Spectacle's GUI. Typical cases would be taking a delayed screenshot and wanting to include or exclude the mouse pointer.

Your Spectacle settings are saved in *~/.config/spectaclerc* but it's advisable *not* to edit this file directly. Instead, use Spectacle's GUI where possible.

---

I'm guessing from

> Can I make application activated on PrintScreen button?

that when you press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, you want Spectacle to be focused if it is already open (but minimized). And if it isn't running, you want it to start when you press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>.

If you install *wmctrl* (available in the Universe repository), you can use

```
wmctrl -xa spectacle.spectacle || spectacle -g
```

as a shortcut. This command checks to see if Spectacle is running: if it is running, the Spectacle GUI is brought into focus. If Spectacle is not running, the command launches Spectacle.

If that is indeed what you want, make a new *custom shortcut* with *Print* as the trigger and the code above as the action. You'll be warned that there is a conflict and you'll be asked if you want to *reassign* the function. Do so.

Answer (score 1):

I Think you mean Copy To Clipboard ASAP

You can use the shortcut META+Print Screen  (Meta is Windows Key)

but this action will complete the default action which normally is Save to Screenshot folder
If that's the case, Open Spectacle, go to configure and change to this:
[image]